# What was the difficulty in enumerative geometry problems before physics?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, mathematical-physics, moduli-space, string-theory, mirror-symmetry

I have read the book 'Enumerative Geometry and String Theory' by Katz, and it left me with some questions. It is outlined in the text how ideas from String theory and TQFT has enriched enumerative geometry. Examples of problems that couldn't be solved, but were solved using these methods are:

1. 'Number' of rational curves of degree $d$ in the quintic threefold
2. Number of degree $d$ curves passing through $3d-1$ points in $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Personally, the fact that the second problem with $d\geq 5$ couldn't be solved without the help of physics was mind-boggling, especially when the answer is as small as 87,304. The classical methods outlined in the text seem pretty strong, and I want to know what exactly was the difficulty was to solving these problems.

One point that Katz mentions is that the moduli space of stable maps was motivated by physics. But historically Deligne and Mumford compactified similar moduli spaces, and why couldn't people use this moduli space to solve the problems?

Please note that I am not fully aware of some 'subtleties' that might be present in enumerative geometry, since I know only very crudely how enumerative problems are solved. If you could identify the hard point inside(or outside!) the follwing steps of solving enumerative problems that would be nice.

1. Find a moduli space compactifying the geometric objects considered.
2. Compute the cohomology ring of the moduli space.
3. Identify what needs to be integrated over the moduli spade.
4. Find the excess intersection, and show that the answer is actually enumerative.

Comment: part 3 is finding suitable so called virtual cycles in $\mathcal{M}$ that are of dimension zero, given that the "expected dimension" of the moduli problem is zero. This involves usually a perfect obstruction theory.

Comment: Regarding the Deligne-Mumford compactification: that moduli space parametrizes stable curves up to isomorphism, i.e. so-called "abstract curves." Such a space will intrinsically not have all that much to say about enumeration of curves in projective space *especially* in the cases you mentioned where the curve in question are rational, so Deligne-Mumford doesn't really apply at all (the basic assumption in working with that space is generally that $g \geq 2$).

Comment: 4 is not always true, not in Gromov-Witten theory at least.